# How to Capture a live stream from Windows Media Server 2008

Tags: c#, video-capture, wms

I want to capture the live stream from windows media server to filesystem on my pc
I have tried with my own media server with the following code. but when i have checked the 
out put file i have found this in it.

```
FileStream fs = null;

try
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://mywmsserver/test");
    CookieContainer ci = new CookieContainer(1000);
    req.Timeout = 60000;
    req.Method = "Get";
    req.KeepAlive = true;
    req.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 99;
    req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3";
    req.ReadWriteTimeout = 90000000;
    req.CookieContainer = ci;
    //req.MediaType = "video/x-ms-asf";

    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    Stream resps = resp.GetResponseStream();


    fs = new FileStream("d:\\dump.wmv", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = resps.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {

        fs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
finally
{
    if (fs != null)
        fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: there is no such thing as "C#.NET". It's just "C#".

Comment: I can't see what this has to do with makefiles, removed tag

Comment: Works!, but i would like some more insight on what possibilities there would be otherwise, is this performance effecient? say, if i would like to capture many cams?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a question here...but... this code is very handy!!

I've been looking for a way to capture the ASF video stream from a WiFi webcam for a home security application... and this does it.

You need these at the start of your C# code.. then compile and run.

using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;

Thanks for the post!